# iphone ios 3.0.1, device is not being able to get a device token nor reporting an error?

Tags: iphone, push-notification, ios3.0

ok i have an iphone with ios 3.0.1
i have wifi turned on, no cellular network.

I have created my provisioning profile, my certificate correctly. why?... gonna tell you in a while
anyway, when i run the application, i have put NSLog in

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app  didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken 

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)err
```

but when i run the application i don't get anything, no success nor error.

anyway i tried the SAME APPLICATION and run it on iphone with ios 4.0 and it did work and it printed the device token.
Oh and they are both using the same wifi network.

could it be the device? the ios ? or the security of the wifi connection?
and shouldn't at least give me an error in that case?

could that be caused by the missing library file

```
warning: Unable to read symbols for "/Library/MobileSubstrate/MobileSubstrate.dylib" (file not found).
```

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2265/_index.html) :

> #### No Delegate Callbacks
>
> When the first push-capable app is installed on a device, iOS attempts to
>   establish a persistent network connection to the push service that
>   will be shared by all push-capable apps on the device.
>
> **If neither delegate callback
>   `application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:`
>   nor
>   `application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:`
>   is called, that means that this
>   connection has not yet been
>   established.**
>
> This is not necessarily an error
>   condition. The device may not have
>   Internet connectivity at all because
>   it is out of range of any cell towers
>   or Wi-Fi access points, or it may be
>   in airplane mode. Instead of treating
>   this as an error, your app should
>   continue normally, disabling only that
>   functionality that relies on push
>   notifications.
>
> Keep in mind that network availability
>   can change frequently. Once the
>   persistent connection to the push
>   service succeeds, one of the
>   previously-mentioned application
>   delegate methods will be called.
>
> Push notifications use the cellular
>   data network whenever possible, even
>   if the device is currently using Wi-Fi
>   for other network activity such as web
>   browsing or email. However, the push
>   service will fall back to Wi-Fi if
>   cellular data service isn't available.
>
> If your device is capable of using the
>   cellular data network, check that it
>   has an active cellular data plan. Turn
>   off Wi-Fi in Settings and see if you
>   can still browse the web with Safari,
>   for example. On the other hand, if the
>   push service is using Wi-Fi, any
>   firewalls between your device and the
>   Internet must allow TCP traffic to and
>   from port 5223.
>
> NOTE: There is a separate persistent
>   connection to the push service for
>   each environment. iOS establishes a
>   persistent connection to the sandbox
>   environment for development builds; ad
>   hoc and distribution builds connect to
>   the production environment.

About second part of your question, `MobileSubstrate` is not the culprit, this is a normal log message... from a jailbroken iPhone :)

Comment: thanks alot i couldn't find such a thing in their documentations. I'll look into it and see my network security maybe it's the cause. I don't think it's the device's connection because i'm able to go online. could be the port thing.
Anyway thanks a lot... AND I'm sorry but it's not a jailbroken iPhone :D. Well that's what they told me in the company anyway; it's not mine and i don't really care :P. Main obssession is compatibility

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/search/index.php?Search=didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken > 2nd reference link :)